# Label and reference in inline mode and enumerate environment

Tags: equations, lists, enumerate, labels

I would like to generate the following list:

[image]

Here the equations are inline and labelled with numbers for later `\ref`.

I have tried using `\begin{aligned}` after `\item` to create an inline math environment, but it does not support `\label`.

Comment: I would like to create a list of conditions (i)-(iii) which are described by equations labelled with (9.2.4)-(9.2.6). After this list, there will be another list of the same form, showing that in other context, conditions (i)-(iii) can also be correspondingly described by other equations (9.2.7)-(9.2.9), as a varied version (i)', (ii)', (iii)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flalign` for example to do the alignment. In the code below I just put the (i), (ii) and (iii) manually.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
  \text{(i)\enskip}&a=b&\label{e1}\\
  \text{(ii)\enskip}&c=d&\label{e2}\\
  \text{(iii)\enskip}&x=y&\label{e3}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Though I would not recommend to do this. There's no reason to create two different enumeration schemes for these equations. If they are to be references as equations then number them as equations only. If they are items in an enumerated list then don't put equation numbers to them. Your way would confuse readers.

The result of the code above:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer and reminder. I will clarify the numbers in the text to avoid confusion.